# Read .desktop files programmatically

Tags: text-processing, c, .desktop

I would like to make a C program (GTK) that reads a `.desktop` file. The only thing I need from the `.desktop` file is the `exec` command. Is there something built into GTK that would allow me to interact with `.desktop` files? Or do I have to use the standard file IO methods?

Comment: I cannot help but wonder what made Gilles et al conclude that this question is "too broad" ... especially in view of: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164131/2141 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/144422/2141 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176035/2141 and ... many more

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GLib's [GKeyFile](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Key-value-file-parser.html) class could be what you are looking for.