# .desktop file. Correct exec path

Tags: command-line, gnome-shell, freedesktop, .desktop

I use Fedora. There are a number of programmes packaged in a security spin. Included desktop files work but open the programmes with root priviliges.

How can I edit the desktop file shown here to open the target without root. I have tried every obvious edit I can think of but am not having any luck.

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=argus
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "su -c 'argus -h; bash'"
TryExec=argus
Type=Application
Categories=System;Security;X-SecurityLab;X-Reconnaissance;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Name=argus
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "sh -c 'argus -h; bash'"
TryExec=argus
Type=Application
Categories=System;Security;X-SecurityLab;X-Reconnaissance;
```

This matches behavior most closely. It could be improved upon by someone who knows argus better than I

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is this version swops 'sh' in for 'su'.
That worked perfectly, thank you!