# Getting Current path in .desktop entry for ICON command

Tags: .desktop

Im trying to make a .desktop file run a .sh which is stored in the same directory as the .desktop. The whole directory needs to be portable and moved from machine to machine.

Now I can get the current path for EXEC command using the method from :

[Getting the current path in .desktop EXEC command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144422/getting-the-current-path-in-desktop-exec-command/144428?noredirect=1#comment269172_144428)

```
Exec=bash -c '"$(dirname "$1")"/run.sh' dummy %k
```

But now I also want it to load icon from the same directory so that it becomes completely portable. But didn't get any success but using the approach as suggested for EXEC command.

This is what I tried:

```
Icon=bash -c '"$(dirname "$1")"/run.sh' dummy %k
```

and

```
Icon=bash -c '"$(pwd)"/data/planet_image_gray.png'
```

But none seem to work. I hope there is a solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

That trick works for the `EXEC` entry because it runs a command, but it doesn't work for `ICON` because it expects either a standard icon name that it can locate in the /usr/share/icons/ directories, or an absolute pathname to a custom image. Modern versions of Desktop don't even accept relative pathnames for custom images.

If you really *must* have a custom image in your portable directory it's possible, but a bit messy. You could do it by having an install script that you run when you move the directory to a new location. The install script would generate a new .desktop file customised for its current location, either using details stored in the script itself, or by using a template file. But that sounds like a lot of messing around to me...